# what happen to return statement in catch block

Tags: javascript

I have tried this code in javascript

```
function abc(){
  try{
     console.log(0);
     throw "is empty";}
  catch(err){
     console.log(1);
     return true;
  }
  finally{return false;}
  return(4);
}
console.log(abc());
```

I got output as false. I understand Finally always execute regardless of result of try catch but what happen to return statement in catch .

Comment: i think you should write throw new Error("is empty")

Comment: try it and tell me

Comment: Ideally, you should not set return variable values in finally block. By using your code you actually suppressing actual error in finally block instead you could have logged error.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> I understand Finally always execute regardless of result of try catch
> but what happen to return statement in catch .

**Return statement** in `catch` will be executed only if the `catch` block is reached, i.e. if there is an error thrown.

For example

```
function example() { 
    try { 
        throw new Error()
        return 1;
    } 
    catch(e) {
        return 2;
    }
    finally { 
    } 
}
```

`example()` will return `2` since an error was thrown before `return 1`.

But if there is a `finally` block and this `finally` block has a `return` statement then this `return` will override `catch` return statement.

For example

```
function example() { 
    try { 
        throw new Error()
        return 1;
    } 
    catch(e) {
        return 2;
    }
    finally { 
        return 3;
    } 
}
```

Now `example()` will return `3`.

In your example, there is a return statement after the finally block. That statement will never get executed.

Try

```
function example() { 
    try { 
        throw new Error()
        return 1;
    } 
    catch(e) {
        return 2;
    }
    finally { 
        return 3;
    } 
   console.log(5)
   return 4;
}
```

It only outputs `3`. `5` is never printed since after `finally` block value is returned.

Comment: What if we have a return in catch block and a console.log in finally? what will be the execution?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt It will print console log of finally and return from catch block if catch block is reached.

Comment: So, is it like return is always executed at the last? No matter in which block it is present?

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt Yes, `return` is always going to be last line in the method execution, only confusion seems to be - which `return`.

Comment: Why doesn't the catch block in your last example return the 2? Because if you add a console.log before that return statement, it will run, meaning it gets in the catch block, but it doesn't run the return. Why doesn't the return in the catch get run? Or does it get run but gets somehow canceled? What happens there?

Answer (score 4):

Finally its always executed the last. So it overrides any other return you have. Therefore, your method returns false