# Is there a way just replace with custom error each async error message without try catch each function?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

let say launch method if executable not found it will throw, the error throw with string type. why it not object `{ message: 'Error failed', additionalInfo: 'trouble', executablePath: 'c:/' }`. it happen to almost puppeteer method. so i need to replace it.

> Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn
> H:/WebGame/GoogleChrome/chromess.exe ENOENT TROUBLESHOOTING:
> https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

instead, below ways.

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor(executablePath) {
    super()
     this.message = 'Error: Failed to launch the browser process!';
     this.executablePath = executablePath;
  }
}

class Application {
  constructor() {
    this.browser;
  }
  async launch(options) {
    try {
      this.browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      return this.browser
    } catch(e) { throw new CustomError(options.executablePath) }
  }

  async close() await this.browser.close()
}
```

theres simply to just replace the error?

Comment: I think instead of throwing you just need to return new CustomError()

Comment: @ColinHale but need to encapsulate to try catch right? in up code. double check try first puppeteer launch. 2nd application launch. why from the first puppeteer create, them not care how the most easy to present error log to debug. it just make other task to someone want fast use puppeteer.  or it have somereason? such a big project. not care in this simple things.

Comment: Sorry I don't know if I am understanding the question.You also need to add a finally catch to the end: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38050857/what-happen-to-return-statement-in-catch-block#:~:text=Return%20statement%20in%20catch%20will,there%20is%20an%20error%20thrown.&text=example()%20will%20return%202,will%20override%20catch%20return%20statement.

Comment: @ColinHale my question is the simply way to just replace error. as u see some puppeteer have many method. launch, newPage, waitForSelector. that all return message error in string. ex, waitforselector return `error css selector #page`. in real use case. we need to know what message, and the css selector in seperate ways `{ message: 'error css selector not found', selector: '#page' }`. because of that,  each method need to encapsulate again in try catch to throw custom error.

Comment: The Stack link I posted shows you how to replace the error in the catch block

Comment: @ColinHale is there  shorter ways? all method have try catch block.

Comment: You have to have the catch block there is no other way

Comment: I'm not really clear either what the point of this is. Are you trying to override the error for all errors or just `browser.launch`? If the former, ...why?

Comment: @ggorlen i want to override, because. i need to know what the value that pass to method  that make error. lets say, launch, executable not found. in real, i need to know the path accurately. user can put everything random length path. if i just substring by index. it stills have some lack, i dont know how long the path exactly. what i can do i will read again from database. it makes double query to database. i just want to log the error. it happen to all method. ex, waitforselector. it gives error in string. yes, i knows the css selector by compare in loop. but it application not efficient.

Comment: @ggorlen it need to do regex in string error. as my application i will predict. it handle 100 users, and maybe more . a user maybe launch 15 page in same time. so total 1500 hit database. i just think in average worst case. what the error send to server is just a code. like codeError  1 is means` failed to launch browser executable not found, exec: 'c:/'`. so in server i just filter by that code. if 1 means that error, with addtional info like executable. and save to database. if so no shorter ways to override the error message.